Xubuntu 22.04: Using PipeWire and Wireplumber, bluetooth headset connects and plays audio but only using HSP/HFP and not A2DP
Very big newbie here, spent the last 90 minutes trying to troubleshoot audio. Here's the Narrative of what happened: I was having trouble connecting my bluetooth headset to Xubuntu. The problem was that the connection would hang and do nothing. I installed Pipewire and replaced PulseAudio, now I could connect my headset, but it would instantly disconnect. Then I installed Wireplumber and everything worked. I connected my headset and was happily listening to audio.
Then I logged out, and when I logged back in, my headset connected automatically, but no longer played audio. Instead I was hearing a crackling/popping noise. Funky. I opened up Pavucontrol and messed around with stuff. Turns out, if I switch to HSP/HFP instead of A2DP everything works (albeit garbage audio quality). And to be clear, both profiles are available in Pavucontrol and the device can switch between both. The A2DP profiles were working when I was in the session where I first installed PipeWire and Wireplumber.
Here's what grinds my gears: it worked perfectly when I was still logged into the session where I initially installed Pipewire and Wireplumber. After logging out and logging back in, this issue began.
Any help would be appreciated. I've already searched through this forum and others to find a solution.

Just stumbled into a roughly-similar issue. Peeked into Debian Wiki — the solution for me was, sudo apt remove pulseaudio-module-bluetooth followed by systemctl --user restart wireplumber. In a second, the headset reconnected in A2DP profile.
